# BalloonItemizedOverlay custom view framelayout with 2 tabs in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs

i m creating one application in which i have displayed one google map using 'Map activity' and then mark some geo points as i required dynamically. now ontap of pin(marker) i have displayed some info which i required, till this is going fine. but now requirement is like ontap of pin which custom layout opens , it has 2 tabs - 1 displays info and 2 has button.i dont how to do it in ballon overlay view?

Comment: I am very much interested in the answer. If you find any solution please post here...